# Prevent rounding when converting number to text

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to convert two columns of numbers (containing both integers and  non-integers) into text and place them under a third column called "range".

Expected outcome:
[image: expected]

Actual outcome:
[image: actual]

The issue is that when I convert it to text, the values  get rounded. 
To do this conversion, I am using the following function to convert them to text.

```
C2 =TEXT(A2,"0")&"-"&TEXT(B2,"0")
```

and this is giving me the rounded values.

Does anyone know how to overcome this?

- I cannot change the column formatting to increase the number of decimal places as I would have unnecessary 0's. e.g i want 7 instead 7.0
- I have tried changing the function to
  `C2 =TEXT(A2,"##.#")&"-"&TEXT(B2,"##.#")` , this helps in not rounding the wanted text. However it also adds an extra '.' decimal point after integers. E.g 7. or 20. And i do not know how to get rid of the extra decimal point.

Very new at this, any help would be appreciated. Open to try macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need VBA code for this. Try this

Check if the cell has decimal or not. You can do that by `=INT(A1)=A1`. Incoporating it in the formula `=IF(INT(A2)=A2,TEXT(A2,"0"),TEXT(A2,"0.0"))`. Similarly for the 2nd cell

`=IF(INT(A2)=A2,TEXT(A2,"0"),TEXT(A2,"0.0")) & "-" & IF(INT(B2)=B2,TEXT(B2,"0"),TEXT(B2,"0.0"))`

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Siddharth Rout. works fine! i was stuck on this for a while